# Clogit wtp interpretation

Tags: survival, odds-ratio, regression-coefficients, clogit

I have performed a clogit with the package survival in R. The aim the work was to estimate the willingness to pay from a discrete choice model. The choice set was composed of 4 attributes, 3 of them with 3 levels and the attribute price with 5 levels. In particular the price was composed by the levels 20, 40, 50, 70 and 90 euros.
My question is related to results interpetation. Why I have obtained a value of WTP much higher than the value that I have proposed? In particular if I made the ratio between the a certain level of the non-monetary term and the coefficient of the price (as follows):

$$WTP=-\frac{β_nonmonetary}{β_price}$$

I obtain a WTP of -237. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: The WTP in conditional logit models can be larger than the price. Assuming you're an economist, it roughly means that consumer surplus is estimated to be positive.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly I am not an economist but I have to analysed these data. I can still understand the larger value of the WTP but I am struggling to understand the meaning of a negative value so big: -237. Could be maybe that the respondents are willing to pay 237 in the case of HAB_100. and when there is the case of HAB_0 there is a lost of the same amount?Therefore we have -237 $?